# Executing MySQL command via Shell script for auth socket plugin

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a shell script to automate the process of installing PHP, MySQL and Nginx.

So far everything is working fine. However, I cannot switch its authentication method from `auth_socket` to `mysql_native_password`.

```
MYSQLPASS=$(openssl rand -base64 32)

sudo apt-get install -y expect

sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server

SECURE_MYSQL=$(expect -c "
set timeout 10
spawn mysql_secure_installation

expect \"Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No: \"
send \"n\r\"

expect \"New password: \"
send \"$MYSQLPASS\r\"

expect \"Re-enter new password: \"
send \"$MYSQLPASS\r\"

expect \"Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : \"
send \"y\r\"

expect \"Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : \"
send \"y\r\"

expect \"Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : \"
send \"y\r\"

expect \"Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : \"
send \"y\r\"

expect eof
")
```

I have to manually do it on the terminal.

```
sudo mysql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<password>';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

Comment: what are you doing with the var `SECURE_MYSQL` ? If your not really using it, ditch the `var=$() stuff, and stop escaping your `"`, etc chars  :-)! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
MYSQLPASS=$(openssl rand -base64 32)

sudo apt-get install -y expect

sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server

SECURE_MYSQL=$(expect -c "
set timeout 10
spawn mysql_secure_installation

expect \"Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No: \"
send \"n\r\"


expect \"Enter current password for root (enter for none):\"
send \"$MYSQLPASS\r\"
expect \"Change the root password?\"
send \"n\r\"


expect \"Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : \"
send \"y\r\"

expect \"Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : \"
send \"y\r\"

expect \"Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : \"
send \"y\r\"

expect \"Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : \"
send \"y\r\"

expect eof
")

echo "$SECURE_MYSQL"
```

Change this part accordingly

For MariaDb/MySQL 5.5:

```
expect "Enter current password for root (enter for none):"
  send -- "\r"
  expect "Set root password?"
  send -- "y\r"
  expect "New password:"
  send -- "${$MYSQLPASS}\r"
  expect "Re-enter new password:"
  send -- "${$MYSQLPASS}\r"
```

For Mysql 8

```
    expect "Enter password for user root:"
    send "$MYSQLPASS\r"
    
    expect "Change the password for root ? ((Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
    send "y\r"
    
    expect "New password:"
    send "$MYSQLPASS\r"
    
    expect "Re-enter new password:"
    send "$MYSQLPASS\r"
    expect "Do you wish to continue with the password provided?(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
send "y\r"
```

As for MariaDB 10.x

```
       expect \"Enter current password for root (enter for none): \"
send \"n\r\"
expect \"Switch to unix_socket authentication \[Y/n\] \"
send \"n\r\"
expect \"Change the root password? \[Y/n\] \"
send \"y\r\"
expect \"New password: \"
send \"$MYSQLPASS\r\"
expect \"Re-enter new password: \"
send \"$MYSQLPASS\r\"
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out.